# WPF throws System.ArgumentException when trying to set background with two way binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am getting the following exception when I attempt the change the background color of a border using two way data binding.

```
{"Must create DependencySource on same Thread as the DependencyObject."}
```

When I first got this error I changed my code to have the colors as static resources hoping it would solve the problem, but it didn't work.

*xaml*

```
<Grid x:Name="BgGrid">
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Color x:Key="ACGreen">#FF0A7E07</Color>
        <Color x:Key="ACYellow">#FFE2BD00</Color>
        <Color x:Key="ACRed">#FFAF0B01</Color>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="GreenBrush" Color="{StaticResource ACGreen}" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="YellowBrush" Color="{StaticResource ACYellow}" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="RedBrush" Color="{StaticResource ACRed}" />
    </Grid.Resources>
    <TabControl Style="{StaticResource LeftTabControl}" Background="#FAFAFAFA" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <TabItem x:Name="ConnectionLabelTab" Style="{StaticResource Tab2}" Focusable="False">
            <TabItem.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border x:Name="ConnectionLabelBorder" Background="{Binding LabelColor, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="70"
                        DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}, Path=DataContext}">
                        <TextBlock x:Name="ConnectionLabelText"
                            Text="{Binding LabelText, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Padding="0,4,0,4"
                            Foreground="#FAFAFAFA" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                            FontSize="10"/>
                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
            </TabItem.HeaderTemplate>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
</Grid>
```

*xaml.cs*

```
public partial class TabPanel : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    Brush labelcolor;
    String labeltext;

    public TabPanel()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        labelcolor = BgGrid.Resources["RedBrush"] as Brush;
        labeltext = "Disconnected";
    }

    public Brush LabelColor 
    { 
        get { return labelcolor; }
        set
        {
            labelcolor = value;
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("LabelColor"));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void SetConnected()
    {
        LabelColor = BgGrid.Resources["GreenBrush"] as Brush;
        LabelText = "Connected";
    }
}
```

Is there a better/proper way to change the background color dynamically? How can I fix my code to stop getting this System.ArguementException? If I comment out setting the LabelColor the code works fine and the text changes as expected.

Comment: is this happening in the SetConnected method?  if so where is that called from?

Comment: Do you know what a thread is?  I do not want to sound patronizing, but your attempted solutions imply that you do not understand the exception message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ill take a stab at this not sure if this will work but you may need to invoke on the dispatcher.

```
public void SetConnected()
{
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => {
      LabelColor = BgGrid.Resources["GreenBrush"] as Brush;
      LabelText = "Connected";
   });
}
```

The reason being,  if the SetConnected method is called from somewhere off of the UI thread (like a timer or something not directly called from the UI), it will need to "reintegrate" back into the UI thread in order to update any of the UI properties.  This is a common thing when dealing with WPF binding.